# How do I compute the expected value of X(\omega)=1/(1-\omega)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let the sample space be $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the probability dx:

$X(\omega)=1/(1-\omega)$.

The support is then $[1, +\infty)$

How do I compute the expected value of this R.V., with this information? What is the pdf? I guess $E[X]$ is +$\infty$ but I can not prove it.

Comment: The law of the unconscious statistician says for any measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, that $\mathbb{E}(g(X))=\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f_X(x) dx$.

Answer (score 2):

$EX$ is $\infty$. $EX=\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1 {1-\omega} d\omega=\infty$.

Comment: Could you help me reconcile the std formula for the computation of the EV: $\int_\infty^{\infty}  x f(x) dx$, with the one you used? What is the pdf for the R.v. in this example?

Comment: @Alchemy If you define $Y(\omega)$ as $\omega$  the $Y$ has density $1$ on $(0,1)$. For any $g$, $Eg(Y)=\int g(x)f(x)dx$ . Here $f(x)=1$ and $f(x) =\frac 1 {1-x}$.

Comment: Sorry, but the integral, according to the LOTUS shouldn't be $EX=\int_0^{\1} \frac 1 {1-\omega} d\omega=\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case :
$$
\mathop{\text E}[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) \,d\,{\text P}(\omega) 
$$
Since $\Omega=[0,\,1]$ and $d{\text P}(\omega)=d\omega$ then
$\mathop{\text E}[X] = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-\omega}\,d\omega = +\infty$.

Comment: Can I ask you why $dx=dP(w)$? Moreover, with the assumption I have, can I conclude that X is continuous? And do I know the pdf? I do not think so, right?

Comment: You are given that $dP(\omega)=d\omega$. What is the meaning of words "the probability dx"? Here the variable is $\omega$, not $x$. Yes, $X$ is definitely continuous and you can find pdf of X. But it is not needed at all.

Comment: sorry to bother you. How would you compute the pdf here?

Comment: @Alchemy Find cdf first: for $x>0$, $1/(1-\omega)\leq x$ $\iff$ $0\leq \omega\leq 1-\frac1x$, so $F(x)=1-\frac1x$.

Comment: If I set x=1/2 I get F(x)=-1

Comment: Oh, sorry. Indeed, $x\geq 1$. The value $\frac{1}{1-\omega}$ cannot be less than 1.

Comment: thank you. I am still not able to understand why $0\leq \omega\leq 1-\frac1x$, implies $F(x)=1-\frac1x$. Perhaps I should ask it in a separate question

Comment: @Alchemy You should first decide, what is the meaning of words "the probability dx". I already asked it.