# How do I compute the CDF and PDF of the following R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let the sample space be $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the probability dx:

$X(\omega)=1/(1-\omega)$.

Am I able to compute the CDF and PDF of that R.V. how? It looks like it is continuous so it should have a pdf. But I can't understand how to compute it.

**Edit**

Here is my attempt:

By the definition of CDF, we have $P(X \leq x)= P(\frac{1}{1-\omega} \leq x)=P(\frac{1}{x} \leq 1-\omega)=P(\omega \leq 1-\frac{1}{x})$

But because $\omega$ is uniform in [0,1], I can use its Cdf to claim that $P(\omega \leq 1-\frac{1}{x})=1-\frac{1}{x}$ so that $P(X\leq x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$. Am I right?

Comment: Why do you keep asking this question?

Comment: It can be computed with the basic transformation technique or CDF method. Give it a try, post your effort and we’ll help you!

Comment: @kimchilover it is actually a different question. I am just asking how could I compute the Pdf or cdf. The other question was about expectation. The R.v is the same, but the question is different. It just came to my mind while I was sorting out the previous one

Comment: $$
\mathbb P(X\leqslant x) = \ldots
$$

Comment: I have just added my attempt. Please, check it out.

Comment: Your attempt is correct. Now differentiate to find the PDF. Of course the expression is only valid for $x \neq 0$. But $X(\omega)=1/(1-\omega)$ is never zero for any $0\leq \omega <1$, so it is no problem.

Comment: Previous questions related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3400856/how-do-i-compute-the-expected-value-of-this-sequence-of-r-v and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399628/how-do-i-compute-the-expected-value-of-x-omega-1-1-omega

Comment: @NapD.Lover Differentiating yields a "density" of $1/x^2$ whose integral does not converge over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Also, $\mathbb P(X\leqslant x) = 1-\frac1x$ does not make sense as $$\lim_{x\to - \infty}1 - \frac1x = 1 $$ when this limit must be zero to be a valid distribution function.

Comment: @Math1000 properly, the CDF is $(1-x^{-1})\mathbb{1}_{x>1}$ and the density is $x^{-2} \mathbb{1}_{x>1}$. I carelessly left out the bounds, but these should check out now.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes sense now.